# How can I wrap the entire page contents in a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code.

```
$(function(){
    $("body").prepend('<div id="loading"><span id="pagename"></span></div><div id="fade_wrapper">');
    $("body").append('</div> <!-- closing #fade_wrapper -->');
});
```

The problem is that chrome auto closes the open `<div id="fade_wrapper">` so that the HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="loading"><span id="pagename"></span></div><div id="fade_wrapper"></div>
```

That closing DIV in the second code shouldn't be there. How can I wrap the entire page contents in a div using jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.wrapInner`:

```
$("body").wrapInner('<div id="loading"...');
```

append and prepend don't work that way.  You prepend/append *nodes*, not *tags*.

It seems like you want to prepend some separate HTML as well.  No matter:

```
$("body").wrapInner('<div id="fade_wrapper">');
$("body").prepend('<div id="loading"><span id="pagename"></span></div>');
```

The `.prepend` is done second so that it will be outside of the wrapping.

Comment: How do I open and close the command? `$("body").wrapInner('<div id="fade_wrapper">');` doesn't close it. I'm off to read the API now.

Found It: `$('.inner').wrapInner('<div class="new" />');` Just needs a closing slash.

Comment: @user1424232 you don't have to close tags like that; it's just part of the jQuery syntax for nodes.  I agree it's a bit strange, but have to realize the difference between working with nodes and tags